# Getting error on initializing spring boot application in aws Lambda

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using java springboot application in Lambda. While running Lambda getting this error. Can someone suggest why this error is coming and how to solve it

```
    Error loading class com.xyz.abc.LambdaHandler: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder has not been registered
    at org.springframework.boot.DefaultBootstrapContext.lambda$get$1(DefaultBootstrapContext.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.DefaultBootstrapContext.getOrElseThrow(DefaultBootstrapContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.DefaultBootstrapContext.get(DefaultBootstrapContext.java:88)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.TextEncryptorConfigBootstrapper.lambda$intitialize$0(TextEncryptorConfigBootstrapper.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.DefaultBootstrapContext.getInstance(DefaultBootstrapContext.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.DefaultBootstrapContext.getOrElseThrow(DefaultBootstrapContext.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.DefaultBootstrapContext.get(DefaultBootstrapContext.java:88)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.TextEncryptorConfigBootstrapper.lambda$intitialize$2(TextEncryptorConfigBootstrapper.java:63)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.DefaultBootstrapContext.close(DefaultBootstrapContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:404)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:144)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.initialize(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:195)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.InitializationWrapper.start(InitializationWrapper.java:35)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder.buildAndInitialize(SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder.java:81)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:93)
    at com.xyz.abc.LambdaHandler.<clinit>(LambdaHandler.java:21)
    ... 2 more

END RequestId: 1363f078-1113-4c06-a846-430d32467251
REPORT RequestId: 1363f078-1113-4c06-a846-430d32467251  Duration: 4540.65 ms    Billed Duration: 4541 ms    Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 44 MB  
Unknown application error occurred
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Comment: Share the code to get proper issue